# The Matrix of the Differentiation map.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $T \in L(P_3(R), P_2(R))$ is the differentiation map defined by $Tp = p'$. Find a basis of $P_3(R)$ and a basis of $P_2(R)$ such that the matrix of T with respect to these bases is

$ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{array} \right)$

I said that a basis for $P_3(R)$ is $(x, \frac{1}{2}x^2, \frac{1}{3} x^3, 1)$ and a basis for $P_2(R)$ is $(1, x, x^2)$ because then

$M(T) = (T(x), T(\frac{1}{2}x^2), T(\frac{1}{3} x^3), T(1))$ is the matrix with columns in $P_2(R)$

Can someone verify if this is correct I'm extremely unsure about my work, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $u \in \mathbb{R}^4$ and let $M$ be the matrix above. Let $v = Mu = (u_1,u_2,u_3)$.

The corresponding polynomials are $p_u(x) = u_1 x + u_2 \frac{1}{2}x^2 + u_3 \frac{1}{3} x^3 + u_4$,
$p_v(x) = u_1 + u_2 x + u_3 x^2$.

A quick check shows that $T p_u = p_u' = p_v$, hence $A$ is the matrix representation of $T$ with respect to the given bases.

**Additional stuff**:

We have a linear operator $T:P_3 \to P_2$ defined by $Tp = p'.$ In particular this means $(Tp)(x) = p'(x)$ for all $x$. Since we can write out $p(x) = \sum_{k=0}^3 p_k x^k$, we can write an explicit formula for $p'$, which
is $p'(x) = \sum_{k=0}^2 p_{k+1} (k+1)x^{k}$.

You have explicit ordered bases above: The ordered basis for $P_3$ is $(x \mapsto x, x \mapsto {1 \over 2} x^2, x \mapsto {1 \over 3} x^3,x \mapsto 1)$ and the
ordered basis for $P_2$ is $(x \mapsto 1, x \mapsto x, x \mapsto x^2)$ (the notation $x \mapsto ...$ just emphasises that these are functions, not just values at some point).

If I take the polynomial $p$ above, it can be expressed in the $P_3$ basis as
the 4-tuple $(p_1, 2 p_2, 3 p_3, p_0)$, and the polynomial $p'$ can be expressed in the $P_2$ basis as the 3-tuple $(p_1,2 p_2,3 p_3)$.

That is, we have the linear map  $M:\mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ given by
$M(p_1, 2 p_2, 3 p_3, p_0) = (p_1,2 p_2,3 p_3)$, or using the variables
$r_1 = p_1, r_2 = 2 p_2, r_3 = 3 p_3, r_4 = p_0$, we have
$M(r_1,r_2,r_3,r_4) = (r_1,r_2,r_3)$, which is the matrix you have given above.

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble converting the notation but it looks like you are saying the same thing I am except you are writing out the polynomials?

Comment: Well, you have the right idea, but are missing some details. I added some details to my answer, hopefully that helps to clarify.